# Group by rows based on time interval - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to group the rows of a table based on the time difference between them.

If the records differ by less than 30 days (time interval), they must be grouped together; otherwise, they are considered separate events. The start will be equal to the start date of the first record, and the end will be equal to the end date of the last record.

**For example**: The following table

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-09-01 |
| 1 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-10-14 |
| 1 | 2023-11-20 | 2023-12-27 |
| 2 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-09-05 |
| 2 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-10-14 |
| 2 | 2023-11-01 | 2023-12-20 |

should become like this:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-10-14 |
| 1 | 2023-11-20 | 2023-12-27 |
| 2 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-12-20 |

For the first case, the first two records should be grouped together as:

start_2n_row - end_1st_row = 2023-09-20 - 2023-09-01 = 19 days

though the 3rd record should be considered seperate event.

I tried to test the LAG but the grouping was not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it groups rows in a PostgreSQL table according to a 30-day time period using recursion. For each group inside of each id, it determines the earliest start date and most recent end date. When using the query, substitute your_table for the name of your table.

```
WITH RECURSIVE interval_groups AS (
  SELECT id, start, end, start AS group_start, end AS group_end, 0 AS group_num
  FROM your_table
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM your_table prev
    WHERE prev.id = your_table.id
      AND prev.end >= your_table.start - INTERVAL '30 days'
      AND prev.start <= your_table.start
  )
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT t.id, t.start, t.end,
         ig.group_start,
         CASE WHEN t.end > ig.group_end THEN t.end ELSE ig.group_end END,
         ig.group_num
  FROM your_table t
  JOIN interval_groups ig ON t.id = ig.id
    AND t.start <= ig.group_end + INTERVAL '30 days'
    AND t.end >= ig.group_start
)
SELECT id, MIN(group_start) AS start, MAX(group_end) AS end
FROM interval_groups
GROUP BY id, group_num
ORDER BY id, start;
```

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH RECURSIVE GroupCTE AS (
SELECT
    id,
    start,
    end,
    1 AS group_id
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id, start

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t.id,
    t.start,
    t.end,
    CASE
        WHEN t.start - lag(g.end) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.start) 
  <= interval '30 days'
        THEN g.group_id
        ELSE g.group_id + 1
    END AS group_id
FROM GroupCTE g
JOIN your_table t ON g.id = t.id
WHERE t.start >= g.start
)
SELECT
id,
MIN(start) AS start,
MAX(end) AS end
FROM GroupCTE
GROUP BY id, group_id
ORDER BY id, start;
```